# Google Sheets: Copy selected cells as CSV using a keyboard shortcut

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, tampermonkey

I frequently need to copy selected cells from Google Sheets and paste them as CSV. I want to add a keyboard shortcut like `Cmd+Shift+C` (macOS) or `Ctrl+Shift+C` (Windows) to copy the selected cells as CSV to the clipboard.

##### What I've Tried:

1. **Google Apps Script**: I found a function in Google Apps Script to copy selected cells as CSV. I can't get this function to actually add a button to the UI.

```js
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Copy Selected Cells as CSV', 'copySelectedCellsAsCSV')
      .addToUi();
}

function copySelectedCellsAsCSV() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var values = range.getDisplayValues(); // Use getDisplayValues to get formatted values
  var csvData = textArrayToCsv_(values);
  
  // Logging the CSV data (You can replace this with code to write to a file or other destination)
  Logger.log(csvData);
}

function textArrayToCsv_(data) {
  // @from https://stackoverflow.com/a/72689533/13045193
  'use strict';
  return (
    data.map(row => row.map(value => `"${value.replace(/"/g, '\\"')}"`))
      .map(row => row.join(', '))
      .join('\n')
  );
}
```

2. **Tampermonkey**: I considered using Tampermonkey for adding custom JavaScript to capture keyboard events, but I'm unsure how to integrate it with Google Apps Script.

##### Questions:

1. Is it possible to directly assign a keyboard shortcut to a Google Apps Script function within Google Sheets?
2. If not, how can I use Tampermonkey or another method to add a keyboard shortcut for this function?
3. Are there any best practices or recommended approaches for this task?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Have you already tried setting up a Sheets macro instead? A macro should allow you to map your function to a specific keyboard shortcut though you're limited to `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + 0-9`

Comment: @DuuEyn Can I export selected cells as CSV with a macro? I don't know about their capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

Copy to Clipboard:

html dialog:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      input{padding:2px 5px 2px 0px;margin:5px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type='text' id="txt1" value="<?= csv ?>" /> 
    <br><input type="button" value="Close" onClick="copyToClip();"/>
    <script>
      function copyToClip() {
        document.getElementById("txt1").select();
        document.execCommand('copy');
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(() => {google.script.host.close();}).justReturn();
      }
      console.log("Scripts")
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

google apps script code:

```
function getSelected() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const rgl = sh.getActiveRangeList();
  let rl = breakUpRangeList(ss,sh,rgl);
  const a = rl.getRanges().map((rg)=> rg.getValue());
  //Logger.log(a.join(','))
  return a.join(',');
}

function launchCopyDialog() {
  let t =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('ah2');
  t.csv = getSelected();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(t.evaluate(),"Copy Dialog")
}

function justReturn() {
  return;
}
```

Demo:

[image]